# Is there a way to get <paper-toolbar> to take up the entire width of the screen using Polymer Starter Kit?

Tags: android, ios, polymer, polymer-1.0, mobile-application

I want my `<paper-toolbar>` to span the entire width of the page like this:

[image: Desired look]

However, the Polymer Starter Kit has the `<paper-menu>` taking up the left margin in the upper left corner like this:

[image: Problem look]

## Question

> **How do I get my Polymer Starter Kit to look like the first picture and not the second?**

- i.e., `<paper-toolbar>` filling the entire screen width.
- I still want to keep the  `<paper-menu>` and `drawer` effect. I just want it under the `<paper-toolbar>`.
- Can you include a Plunker or JSBin with your answer please if possible?

Comment: Isn't that just having the `paper-toolbar` *outside* of the `paper-drawer-panel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just have to insert a `paper-drawer-panel` inside a `paper-header-panel`.

http://jsbin.com/jamelu/edit?html,output

Comment: Upvoted and accepted. I couldn't actually get your JSbin to work. But it was the right idea and pointed me in the correct direction. So... upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to wrap the PSK `<paper-drawer-panel>` inside a `<paper-header-panel>` just like @NeilJohnRamal suggested.

Like this...

#### Code

```
<body>  
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <paper-header-panel>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name">My App</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div class="fit">
        <paper-drawer-panel>
          <div drawer>
            <paper-menu>...</paper-menu>
          </div>
          <paper-header-panel main>
            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div class="content fit">
              <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">                                                
                <section data-route="page01">
                  <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
                </section>
              </iron-pages>
            </div>
          </paper-header-panel>
        </paper-drawer-panel>
      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </template>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```